# Errors from running `import pandas as pd`

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have been tortured by errors out of `import pandas as pd` for a long time. The major types I have dealt with are the following:

Error type 1:

```
ImportError
```

Error type 2:

```
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Comment: The underlying issue is that mac ships a broken-by-default locale setting.

Comment: Thanks, so is there a way to solve those errors above by tackling this `broken-by-default local setting`?

Comment: `IPython Notebook locale error [duplicate]` link above and the first answer of the link solve all the errors above.

Answer (score 0):

For Error Type 1:

I have no idea the cause of the problems, but I figured out a way to solve them.

The major solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061426/importerror-no-module-named-pandas/39145104#39145104)

For Error type 2:

I encountered this error after I install matplotlib package into the trypandas environment. Once I removed matplotlib, everything goes back to normal.

I could not make this error go away while installing matplotlib. I installed bokeh instead of matplotlib, and there is no problem.