# FAIL: pandas in python3 jupyter notebook

Tags: macos, python-3.x, package, conda

My apologies in advance - I have read through multiple sites and tried multiple things, but am still having trouble.

On OSX. Am trying to execute "import pandas as pd" in a jupyter notebook with Python 3, but receive the following message: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I created a new conda environment

```
conda create -n py3x python=3
```

activated it

```
source activate py3x
```

then opened jupyter

```
jupyter notebook
```

Did not work.

Tried this, but that seemed to default to Python 2: [ImportError: No module named 'pandas'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061426/importerror-no-module-named-pandas)

I've also tried (perhaps?) every iteration from the following: [Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook)

I have python 3 in jupyter notebook now, but none of the packages from anaconda. I also tried updating Anaconda (had already done Anaconda3 graphical install)

```
conda update anaconda
```

And that just said "All requested packages already installed"

Any further thoughts on terminal command lines to help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `conda install jupyter` in the newly created environment after activating it?

Comment: Thanks, Nehal - yes - I did try that. Just tried it again ... source activate py3x
(Canopy 64bit) KMB-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kmb$ conda install jupyter pandas
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at //anaconda:

Then, after opening a jupyter notebook and attempting pandas [import pandas as pd], terminal provides: 

    ERROR | No such comm target registered: ipython.widget

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/397

Comment: Yes! Thank you @NehalJWani! It was 100% kernelspec... the path for calling python was pointing to the wrong environment

Comment: Can I suggest you turn the solution comment as an answer (which can be to your own question) for the benefit of others that meet the same issue.