# No module named pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I am trying to make a simple stock market program using pandas to import the data. I have installed Anaconda which said that it installed pandas along with it, as well as Python 2.7. I use PyCharm as my IDE. When I run:

```
import pandas as pd

from pandas_datareader import data
```

I receive the error message

```
import pandas as pd

ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I am not sure why it is giving me this error message so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you set the proper project interpreter in Pycharm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'pandas'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061426/importerror-no-module-named-pandas)

Answer (score 3):

When entering the command to run your file, make sure you specify which version of python you're using. For example, instead of `python filename.py`, use `python3 filename.py` or `python2 filename.py`

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it using **sudo** ...

`sudo pip3 install pandas`

for ubuntu ... it worked got me. pip or pip3 .. as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `pip install pandas` and things will work.

Comment: I just did that and PyCharm still displays the same error message.

Comment: Let's get back to first principles here... Open a command-line, type python, and then `import pandas as pd` do you get an error?

Comment: yes: python import pandas as pd gives me a syntax error and then

Comment: python then on the next line import pandas as pd gives me "python" is not defined

Comment: where's python installed?

Comment: locally. I am not sure exactly where in my folders but I installed it directly off the python website, the same with anaconda

Comment: Can you find it or whatever the windows equivalent is?

Comment: Python is at usr/bin/Python

Comment: and Anaconda is at Anaconda2/bin/python

Comment: I have changed my interpreter to anaconda on pycharm and downloaded the panda package on the pycharm application. it only worked for one run then does not displays the same module error as before. the same thing happened when i ran pip install pandas when my interpreter was python 2.7 on pycharm

Comment: Anaconda uses conda, so for that, you may need to `Anaconda2/bin/conda install pandas`. Now type `Anaconda2/bin/python` and type `import pandas as pd`. Your ImportError should be gone now.

Comment: I think that would work but what would the code look like? Mine is: 'from Anaconda2/bin/python import pandas as pd'. It is now returning a syntax error  on the '/' and I still am not sure if it is still importing pandas because I can only view one error message at a time

Comment: Get out, back into the command prompt and try the Anaconda commands again

Comment: It said "all requested packages are already installed". I then went back into my IDE and tried the commands again only to display the same syntax error message for the '/'s

Comment: Ok, so you can load the right python? Type `import pandas as pd`

Comment: The same error message still displays in pycharm but not in the terminal

Comment: Point PyCharm to Anaconda's python?

Comment: I have also done that and locally installed pandas and pandas_datareader and still the same error messages

Comment: Clearly something else is wrong here, chat me up, share your screen and I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: I figured out why. I have the free version of PyCharm and the scientific tools such as pandas, matplotlib and numpy can only be used is the paid version. Simple fix but thanks for all of your time and help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `pandas` is not installed locally on your computer. Luckily, this is a simple task to accomplish by opening up either a Terminal or Command Prompt (depending on your OS), and typing in the command `pip install pandas`. This will install pandas and you will be good to go!

Comment: I did that and it still displays the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Anaconda installs a Python version of its own, and likely the Python version is Python 3. When you use PyCharm IDE as your editor, you are using another version of Python (Python2). For my Mac, Anaconda's Python is installed under `/anaconda3/bin` and my default Python is installed under `/usr/bin/python`.

I recommend you either config PyCharm to use Anaconda's Python, or use Anaconda's Jupyter your project. Jupyter is arguably a stronger tool considering that you are doing data analytics task.

Also, for Anaconda's python, you shoud use `conda install pandas` instead of `pip install pandas` to install additional packages. This is not necessary this time since it's already installed.

Comment: Whenever I go to the interpreters page on PyCharm to choose Anaconda, only python 2.7 and python expo and expo 2 appear. In finder I looked up anaconda and all I found was the application "anaconda navigator". Is this correct?

Comment: I don't use PyCharm myself, so I'm not sure if the interpreter if working correctly. For Anaconda tho, you can open the Anaconda navigator from applications folder and open up Jupyter from there. It will use Anaconda's Python by default.

Comment: The same error message appears in Jupyter notebook on anaconda. I am using the exact same code as listed above. Sorry to bother u  :)

Comment: Hmm interesting. Maybe try `pip freeze` and `conda list` to see what you have in respective Python? Pandas should be installed when you installed Anaconda.